# Making an API call after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am using React with Redux-toolkit. Let's say I need to fetch some data (let it be an array of numbers), then display those numbers on the page as a list, and then immidiately loop that array and make an API request using each number as an argument. This should happen by clicking on a button.
So, button component looks like this:

```
export const Button: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const onClickButton = () => {
    dispatch(fetchNumbers())
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={onClickButton}>
      <Icon />
      <Text>Run</Text>
    </Button>
  )
}
```

this is extra reducers:

```
export const fetchNumbers = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/numbers',
  async () => {
      return await someAPICall()
  }
)

export const fetchItem = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/item',
  async (number: number) => {
    return await someAnotherAPICall(number)
  }
)
```

Ideally, I want my logic to be like:

```
const onClickButton = () => {
    dispatch(fetchNumbers())
    .then(numbers => {
       numbers.forEach(num => fetchItem(num))
    })
  }
```

But unfortunatelly dispatch doesn't return a promise so I can't then after it.
I know this is some elementary action but I found myself having no idea how to perform it using Redux-toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that `dispatch(fetchNumbers())` does return a promise - buy your types don't reflect that.

You need to correctly type your `dispatch` type as shown here [in the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type)

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed this part in documentation.